# Figuring out value of exponential function as n approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

So the question is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_2^4 e^{(x+\frac{x^3}{n})}dx$ and justify how you obtained the limit.

Here is my idea so far: let's say that $f_n(x) =  e^{(x+\frac{x^3}{n})}$.

Now as $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$, can we say that  $e^{(x+\frac{x^3}{n})} = e^x$?

And if this is the case, how do we proceed and justify it, and if not, why not?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to squeeze the integral.  We can say
$$\int_2^4 e^{x}dx\lt \int_2^4 e^{(x+\frac{x^3}{n})}dx=\int_2^4 e^xe^{\frac{x^3}{n}}dx \lt\int_2^4e^xe^{\frac {4^3}n}dx=e^{\frac {64}n}\int_2^4e^xdx$$
where the first inequality comes because we decreased the integrand, and the second because we used the upper limit for $x$ to increase the integrand.  Now the $n$ is not inside the integral and you can take your limit.

Answer (score 1):

> Now as $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$, can we say that  $e^{(x+\frac{x^3}{n})} = e^x$?

Yes.

> And if this is the case, how do we proceed and justify it, and if not, why not?

If you would like to pass the limit under the integral sign, I suggest the dominated convergence theorem. Can you find a function that dominates your sequence on the domain in question?

Comment: Would $e^5$ work as a function that dominates the current function on the given domain? I say this is $e^5>e^4-e^2$ which is just the integral evaluated with the given limits.

Comment: yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

You implicitly evaluated the limit of $f_n(x)$ then you wanted to integrate that limit, while the question asks you to evaluate the integral, then find the limit. This doesn't necessarily hold all the time.

To show this, you need to show that

$1)$ Every $f_n(x)$ is integrable on $[2,4]$

$2)$ $f_n(x)$ converges **uniformly** to $f(x)=e^x$.

Only then can you claim that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_2^4 f_n(x)dx = \int_2^4 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)dx= \int_2^4 f(x)$.

Can you show this?

**Edit:**

To show $1$, fix an $n \geq 1$. Now consider $f_n(x)$. $f_n(x)$ on $[2,4]$ is Riemann integrable iff

- It is bounded
- It is continuous almost everywhere, or equivalently that the set of discontinuities is of zero Lebesgue measure

Can you show this for $f_n(x)$?

To show $2$, you can use any of the many uniform convergence tests. For example, the $L-$test works here.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would show that those conditions are fulfilled. Would you happen to know how?

Comment: @Mathmaniac Check the new Edit, should guide you for the answer

Comment: I think I have a way to solve it using ideas from your answer. Please let me know if my answer is correct.

I basically show that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ uniformly. Let $\epsilon>0$. We find an N s.t whenever n>N, for all $x\in[2,4]$, we have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| = 0$.

So we have $|e^{x+\frac{x^2}{n}}-e^x| <e^5$ for any $x\in[2,4]$.

Then we choose N s.t whenever n>N, we have $|e^{x+\frac{x^2}{n}}-e^x| < \epsilon$

Thus, we can then use the dominated convergence theorem to compute the limit of the integral, which happens to be $e^4-e^2$ (unless I am mistaken).